# macOS update Electron Builder strange behavior

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I've implemented an Electron update for macOS with Electron Builder but I've noticed a strange behavior during the update.

- I publish to a public github repository a version 1.0.1, let' say;
- I then open my currently installed 1.0.0 version;
- I receive the prompt to update;
- I press restart which does quit the app and start installing the updates;
- ISSUE: but the update takes 30-45 seconds to install.

So if I open the app again after 20 seconds (after starting the actual update), the same update prompt is there with asking me if I want to update, and I become stuck within an update loop prompt, where I hit "Yes" for update, open the app again, seeing the prompt and so on.

The idea of displaying an info message for users "Please don't open the app for 1 min after hitting the update button" is not actually a viable solution.

Is there any way we could add a loading view while the actual update is being made? Or can I catch the pending update and restrict them to open the app somehow? It only happens on macOS.

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/6058

I see a somehow related issue here, but it didn't help that much.

```
"electron": "^24.0.0",
"electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
macOS version: Catalina
```